# javascript display:none for each <span> components in a specified paragraph

Tags: javascript, html

I have a paragraph displaying over 10,000 lines of text and wanted to onclick remove all of them from displaying without hiding the paragraph they're displayed in (ie individually remoing each line of text by changing the span style="display:block" to "display:none"). I have other elements in the <p> that I don't want to be hidden, only the span's.

I can do them line by line, but that is not viable for the number of lines involved. Is there a quicker way to do this?

```js
function uncheckAll() {
  document.getElementById("Box1").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("Box2").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("Box3").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("Box4").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("Box5").style.display = "none";

}
```

```html
<body>
<p id="main" style="display:block" contenteditable="true">
<span id="Box1" style="display:block">text 1.</span>
<span id="Box2" style="display:block">text 2.</span>
<span id="Box3" style="display:block">text 3.</span>
<span id="Box4" style="display:block">text 4.</span>
<span id="Box5" style="display:block">etc.....</span>
</p>

<button style="height:50%;width:10%" onClick="uncheckAll()">Clear</button>
</body>
```

Comment: You should avoid setting/manipulating inline styles to begin with; a _proper_ way to do this, would be to give the `p` element itself a class, and then hide the span elements via that using your stylesheet. Something like `p.hideSpanChildren span { display: none; }`

Comment: On a side note...unless the DIV's can be re-activated somehow (which I don't see in this example)...you might consider removing the element instead of hiding it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```js
const uncheckAll = () => {
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#main span');

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
#main span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p id="main" style="display:block" contenteditable="true">
  <span id="Box1">text 1.</span>
  <span id="Box2">text 2.</span>
  <span id="Box3">text 3.</span>
  <span id="Box4">text 4.</span>
  <span id="Box5">etc.....</span>
</p>

<button style="height:50%;width:10%" onClick="uncheckAll()">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

its easier

```js
const uncheckAll = _ => {
  document.getElementById('#main').classList.add('hide-all');
};
```

```css
.hide-all > span { display:none; }
```